# Angular 4 - Fill select form value based on fetch Http GET method

Tags: html, angular, drop-down-menu

I have successfully fetch data using GET method in Angular. However now I want to put this fetched values as options in the `select form` but I cannot figure it out.

Any workaround with this?

Comment: there are multiple ways to accomplish this, what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You could make the select accessable via #select directive in your -Tag. Then you could simply reset your select @ViewChild with the fetched options.

You also might want to check out the reactive form guide at:
https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#the-data-model-and-the-form-model

Answer (score 0):

If you get the data as an array, you can use ngFor in options to loop through the data.

```
<select class="form-control" >
    <option value=""></option>
    <option *ngFor="let item of data">{{item.optionName}}</option>
  </select>
```

Please check if this is the case.

Comment: This is the one that I have tried, but instead of regular array, I looped it through Observables array and that resulted in error.

Comment: okay, could you please mention the error message, and did you mentioned the type of variable in your component file.

Comment: Nevermind, I changed `formControlName` into `name` in select tag and now it worked!